# How to Create string array with Angular Reactive Form without triggering submit on Enter?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which has a few properties. Hobbies should be a `string[]`.

```
this.myReactiveForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      hobbies: [this.fb.array([])]
})
```

I then have my form. I'm using keydown prevent default because I don't want the enter key submitting the form.

```
<form [formGroup]="myReactiveForm" (ngSubmit)="submitMyReactiveForm()" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
 // other inputs for the other fields.
 <div class="form-group mt-3">
   <label for="hobbies">Hobbies</label>
    <input type="text" formArrayName="hobbies" class="form-control" />
    <span class="mt-1 small text-muted d-block">Type and hit enter after each hobby.</span>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="myReactiveForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What I'd like to have happen is the user enters in a string in the input, hits enter, and that string is added to a string[] of "hobbies" bound the form group. Then, when the user is ready, they click the "submit" button. But I'm not having much luck with the syntax. Any help on how to do this?

Comment: One approach would be to call the `submitMyReactiveForm()` on button click instead of `ngSubmit`

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-formarray-example-in-reactive-forms/#:%7E:text=The%20FormArray%20is%20a%20way,a%20FormControl%20%2C%20or%20another%20FormArray%20.&text=Because%20it%20is%20implemented%20as,it%20easier%20dynamically%20add%20controls.) explains, step by step, what you need to use form arrays. Basically, in your situation, you first need to use *ngFor to iterate the hobbies array, like this:

```
<div formArrayName="hobbies">
  <div *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies().controls; let i=index">
      <input type="text" [formGroupName]="i" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

After that, whenever the user press enter, you need to create a form group for each hobby and add it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to call the `submitMyReactiveForm()` on button click instead of `ngSubmit`

```
   <button (click)="submitMyReactiveForm()" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="myReactiveForm.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in the component:

```
// On the component, hobbie initial list
public hobbiesList = [
    { id: 'option1', name: 'option1' },
    { id: 'option2', name: 'option2' },
    { id: 'option3', name: 'option3' }
];

// On the component, add hobbie function
hobbiesAdd = (hobbie) => ({id: hobbie, name: hobbie});

// On the create reactive form, if has value you include "oldValue || []" in the hobbies field value
//...
this.myReactiveForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      hobbies: [[]]
});
//...
```

Use something like this in the HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myReactiveForm" (ngSubmit)="submitMyReactiveForm()" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
  <!--other inputs for the other fields-->
  <label>Select or add hobbies</label>
  <ng-select 
    [multiple]="true"
    [items]="hobbiesList"
    [addTag]="hobbiesAdd"
    formControlName="hobbies"
    name="hobbies"
    bindValue="id" 
    bindLabel="name" 
    placeholder="Select or add hobbies"
  >
  </ng-select>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="myReactiveForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```